# Get post meta value array in serialized data

Tags: serialization

I saved the information inside the database by Select-Option as serialized data.
this is my data in db :

```
a:2:{i:0;s:7:"#00CC6A";i:1;s:7:"#8E8CD8";}
```

when i want get posts with this query :

```
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'showposts' => 5,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_my_color',
                'value' => '#8E8CD8',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    ));
```

This works . and i can get the post which value_meta is  *#8E8CD8*
when i want to get post with array value , like this :

```
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'showposts' => 5,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_my_color',
                'value' => array('#8E8CD8','#00CC6A'),
                'compare' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    ));
```

It doesn 't works .
i tried everything like :

```
serialize(array('#8E8CD8','#00CC6A'))
```

and this :

```
   'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'       => '_my_color',
        'value'     => '#8E8CD8',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => '_my_color',
        'value'     => '#00CC6A',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
    ),array(
        'key' => '_my_price_wd',
        'value' => '585000',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
```

but i want AND result with   _my_color_   and   _my_price_wd_ 
i can't get relation with OR